# Как удалить некоторые слова из текста?

Tags: javascript, imacros

Ребята, как удалить некоторые слова из текста. Есть код:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".replace('Мама','');")
```

Вот я допустим спарсила какой-то текст. Ну например... "Мама мыла раму". Как мне прописать в коде так, чтобы слова "Мама" и "раму" удалить, а оставить только слово "мыла". Это как-то можно осуществить через ".replace" , но я не знаю как? Извините, что возможно некорректно выражаюсь)) Надеюсь вы меня поняли)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берём те же регулярные выражения из вашего недавнего вопроса и немного их преобразуем:

```js
function update_elem(){
  elem_1 = $('#elem_1').text().replace(/мама|раму/ig,'');
  
  $('#elem_1').text(elem_1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elem_1">Мама мыла раму</div>
<button onclick="update_elem();">Обновить</button>
```

В данном примере я искал слова "мама" и "раму" в строке. Символ `|` это выражение "или". Модификатор `i` указывает, что мы игнорируем регистр символов, а модификатор `g` указывает на глобальный поиск по всей строке. Если его не указать, то поиск завершится после первого же найденного вхождения.

Если вам требуется оставить только определённые слова из строки, то следует использовать метод `match()`, а не `replace()`:

```js
function update_elem(){
  elem_1 = $('#elem_1').text().match(/мыла/ig,'');
  
  $('#elem_1').text(elem_1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elem_1">Мама мыла раму</div>
<button onclick="update_elem();">Обновить</button>
```

Рекомендую вам ознакомиться с документацией по [объекту RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). С их помощью можно многое сделать, если изучить их возможности. :)

Comment: Да, но как мне прописать это в imacros. Из примера: SET !VAR1 EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".replace('Мама','');")

Comment: Вместо `.replace('Мама','')` пишете `.replace(/мама|раму/ig,'')`. Ваш код в целом рабочий. Просто надо первым параметром не обычную строку передавать, а регулярное выражение.

Comment: SET !VAR1 EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".replace(/мама|раму/ig,'');") - Я правильно поняла?!

Comment: @Машуня да, вы поняли абсолютно верно.

Comment: @And это уже другая задача. У ТС-а задача не оставить определённые слова, а удалить определённые слова. Разница большая.

Comment: @And Кстати говоря, это тоже хотела узнать. Если я спарсила большое предложение, то как оставить конкретное слово, ну например то же слово "мыла".

Comment: @And как был поставлен вопрос, так был дан и ответ.

Comment: @And Я вопрос прочитал правильно. "Допустим" применялось только к парсингу. А вопрос был чёткий! "как удалить два слова?" Если ТС-у что-то не нравится - он уточнит. А вот вы раздуваете из мухи слона. Если вам что-то не нравится, пишите свой ответ.

Comment: @Машуня обновил ответ с соответствии с вашим уточнением.

Comment: А вам, уважаемый @And советую быть чуть более терпеливым, это раз, а во-вторых не придумывать проблемы из ничего.

Comment: @And Подумайте на досуге, не несёт ли негативный смысл оборот "ваше мега-выражение". Вы хотели обидеть другого человека? Принизить? Хотели посмеяться? Я не понимаю, толи вы не замечаете этого негатива, толи вы считаете, что это нормально. При этом вы совершенно спокойно вешаете на других людей ярлыки (типа "выскочка"), хотя можно было бы просто указать на недочёт.

Comment: @And а теперь поясняю. Я ссылку на доки оставил не просто так. Использование модификатора \b в данном примере невозможно, так как он работает только с латинницей. С кириллицей надо писать костыли, а от них автор вопроса выпадет в осадок. Вы ежели что по делу, так говорите/пишите. Я уже говорил вам, что если вам что-то не нравится, то пишите свой ответ.